# aurelia variable observer keep recursively calling itself

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i have a recursive problem with a variable change subscription.

```
@bindable year;

yearChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    this.year = this.year + '2017'; //just an example
  }
}
```

So as you can see im using the Aurelia convetion to listen for changes in variable. And when the value of that variable is changed by the user i want to add '2017' to the end of it.

However, when i change the value of year, it causes a recursive call to that same function. And it keeps calling that same function until the application crashes.

Is there a way in Aurelia to stop it from doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`yearChanged` is called whenever the `year` property changes. You are changing the `year` property inside the `yearChanged` callback, so you've created an infinite loop. You should note that the `year` property has already been set when `yearChanged` is called (this is what the callback is `yearChanged` and not `yearIsAboutToChange`).

I would think there would be a number of ways to solve this. The simplest would probably be to create an additional property on your viewmodel. One property would be bindable and could be used for the change detection and the other could be for display purposes.

```
@bindable year;
displayYear;

yearChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    this.displayYear = this.year + '2017'; //just an example
  }
}
```

You could also short-circuit the cycle:

```
@bindable year;

yearChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal && oldVal + '2017' !== newVal) {
    this.year = this.year + '2017'; //just an example
  }
}
```

Again, without more context it is hard to tell, but from the code you have presented, it is quite possible that a [Value Converter](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-value-converters/2) is what you really want though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for representation purpose I would go with value converter.
Still there are legit cases when you would need to do this(wrapping a 3rd party component). Then you can do the following:

```
import {TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-task-queue';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@inject(TaskQueue)
class MyCustomElement {
  constructor(queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  setPropertyOfInterestInternally(value) {
    this.internalSet = true;
    // setting the property here will make the 
    // the underlying mechanics to enqueue a task
    // on the micro task queue - to invoke the change handler
    // it will not be invoked in the current call stack
    this.propertyOfInterest = value;
    // we schedule another task on the micro task queue
    // the arrow function(task) will run after the change handler
    this.queue.queueMicroTask(() => this.internalSet = false);
  }

  propertyOfInterestChanged() {
    // if the set is internal => skip
    if (this.internalSet) { return; }
    // ...
  }
}
```

The tasks are executed *synchronously* - they are *not* awaited to finish an *async* work.